# Add subscriber to Specific Publication List from DE (not all subscriber list)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am looking for a method to add a subscriber(s) to specific publication list. I get the data from Sales cloud contains list of publications subscriber into in DE. Now we are sending them simple email saying you have subscribed into following categories. But before sending them email I need to find a out a way how to add subscriber into specific publication list, he could be a part of one publication list or multiple.

Is this job i can accomplish using Query Activity? Or If export all data from DE onto FTP and then import back directly into specific Publication list (I am not looking for all subscribers list).

Answer (score 1):

Lists, unlike Data Extensions, are not targetable with SQL unfortunately.
You have scripting and Export / import options. For bulk processing you want to go for export / import. It is actually quite performant, but you have to do it for each Publication list separately.

The best way is to do this through the non public part of the FTP account, namely the "safehouse". It's a bit tricky to find out how to get this to work, but if you know, then not a problem at all:

1. Set up a file location of type safehouse, name it "safehouse location".
2. Configure a normal data extract based on the DE of your choice. Data Extract is  is always to safehouse.
3. Follow it up with a file transfer / move to "safehouse location" (this is what one would typically forget)
4. **Now** you can set up an import from Safehouse that will find your file.